# select top n rows after resampling DatetimeIndex

Tags: pandas

I need to get top n rows by some value per week (and I have hourly data).

*data*:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd


dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='11/1/2020', freq="1H")
values = np.random.randint(20, 100500, len(dates))
some_other_column = np.random.randint(0, 10000000, len(dates))
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "value": values, "another_column": some_other_column})
```

My attempt:

```py
resampled = df.set_index("date").resample("W")["value"].nlargest(5).to_frame()
```

It does give top 5 rows but all other columns except for `date` and `value` are missing - and I want to keep them all (in my dataset I have lots of columns but here `another_column` just to show that it's missing).

The solution I came up with:

```py
resampled.index.names = ["week", "date"]
result = pd.merge(
    resampled.reset_index(),
    df,
    how="left",
    on=["date", "value"]
)
```

But it all feels wrong, I know there should be much simpler solution. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output I was looking for. Thanks @wwnde.

```
df["week"] = df["date"].dt.isocalendar().week
df.loc[df.groupby("week")["value"].nlargest(5).index.get_level_values(1), :]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Groupby`, and mask any `nlargest`

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df[df.groupby(df.index.week)['value'].transform(lambda x:x.nlargest(5).any())]
```

Comment: We both learned this / discussed this on another thread, but `week` is deprecated, so `.isocalendar().week` is better. This is a warning I receive on latest version of pandas: `FutureWarning: weekofyear and week have been deprecated, please use DatetimeIndex.isocalendar().week instead, which returns a Series.  To exactly reproduce the behavior of week and weekofyear and return an Index, you may call pd.Int64Index(idx.isocalendar().week)
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.`

Comment: @David Erickson  Old habits die hard

Comment: I would have forgot as well.

Comment: @wwnde this does not give me the desired output but I managed to do it anyway. check out my answer